# How to return a string[] containing values of an Enum

Tags: c#, arrays, string, enums, namespaces

I want to create a dynamic GUI that lists all of an Enum's options as buttons. So, I need a way to pass an Enum type to a method and get back a string array of all the options that enum type can be.

For example, given an Enum declaration in the file Foo.cs:

```
public Enum Fruits {
    Apple,
    Orange,
    Peach
};

public class Foo { ... }
```

I want this returned:

```
{ "Apple", "Orange", "Peach" }
```

I have gone through several permutations of code. Right now I have the following but I am getting an error "*Type or namespace name 'enumeratedType' cannot be found*"

```
public static string[] EnumToStringArray (System.Type enumeratedType) {
    int         enumSize    =   sizeof(enumeratedType);
    string[]    enumStrings =   new string[enumSize];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < enumSize ; i++) {
        enumStrings[i]  =   enumeratedType.getValues()[i].toString();
    }

    return enumStrings;
}
```

Is what I am trying to do possible? I have tried several complete rewrites based on information in this question [Using sentinal values in C# enum (size of enum at compile time)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435209/using-sentinal-values-in-c-sharp-enum-size-of-enum-at-compile-time/9435541#9435541) but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: `Enum.GetNames(typeof (Fruits));`

Comment: It might be a case of using reflection and the PropertInfo class to list things

Comment: Cool, thanks Alexander! Perfect answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string[] names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Fruits));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
public static IEnumerable<string> EnumToStringArray(Type enumeratedType) {
    if (!enumeratedType.IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("Must be an Enum", "enumeratedType");

    return Enum.GetNames(enumeratedType);
}
```

but even that is needless, since `Enum.GetNames(...)` itself throws an `ArgumentException` if the given type is no `Enum`. (Thanks @Alexander Balte).
So you don't need an own function anyway. Simply `Enum.GetNames(typeof(Fruits))` does the job, as others already mentioned.

Comment: If `enumeratedType` is not enum, `Enum.GetNames` will throw `ArgumentException` anyway. I see no reason to check `enumeratedType.IsEnum` and to throw `ArgumentException`.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer for reference, in case someone else does it also more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have misunderstood the meaning of the [`sizeof` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx). It returns the number of bytes (each byte equals 8 bits) that the value type "takes up" when it's lined up with other values in unmanaged memory.

`sizeof` is not useful if you don't use `unsafe` context (like pointers).

For your `Fruits` type, `sizeof(Fruits)` returns `4` since the underlying iteger type is an `Int32` (because that's the default when you don't specify otherwise). An `Int32` requires 32 bits, therefore `sizeof` returns `4`. It doesn't matter if you have 1, 2, 10, or 4294967296 different fruits.

Note that an enum can have multiple names pointing to the same value, like:

```
public enum Fruits {
  Apple,
  Orange,
  Peach,
  ChineseApple = Orange,
}
```

In this example, the enum contains four named constants, but two of them "map to" the same value. In that case, `Enum.GetNames(typeof(Fruits))`, will give you all four names.

But `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Fruit))` will give you a list of four *values* of `Fruit`, two of which are identical. You can't know in advance if the two identical values will be displayed as `Orange` or `ChineseApple`, so don't use this approach if your enum has duplicates like that.